# Error while editing gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with **edit** and **delete**.

When I click **Edit** in the row of gridview, I get **Object Reference not set to an instance of object** in this line of *code-behind*:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
imgbtnEdit.Enabled = true;
```

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

My aspx for gridview is:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton imgbtnEdit = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnEdit");
        Label testing = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("testing");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testing.Text.ToString()))
        {
            imgbtnEdit.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}


<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <center>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/icon.gif" Enabled="false" />
        </center>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <center>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/update.gif" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="/Images/delete.gif" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: not duplicate in my aspx code

Comment: imgbtEdit is in an ItemTemplate. This is not rendered when you move in to edit mode - so the control cannot be found.

Comment: Martin Smellworse what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <center>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/icon.gif" Enabled="false" /></center>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <center>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/update.gif" />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="/Images/delete.gif" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Your image button imgbtnEdit is in the ItemTemplate. When you click to edit, GridView1_RowEditing is called and the row in GridView1 goes into 'edit mode'. When this happens only what is in the EditItemTemplate is rendered, so imgbtnEdit will not exist - which is why you are getting a null reference exception.

Edit: What I tend to do is have variable on the page called isInEditMode and set it to false when the page loads. When rowEditing is called I would write something like:

```
protected void GridView1_rowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
isInEditMode = true;
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
//rebind GridView1
}
```

and in rowdatabound ...

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (isInEditMode == true)
    {
    //get references to the controls in EditItemTemplates
    }
    else
    {
    //get references to the controls in ItemTemplates
    }
}
```

That way you won't be trying to reference controls that don't exist - depending on whether you are viewing or editing the gridview.

Comment: thank you, how do you solve?

Comment: I have added some more to my answer.